# implementing scoring mechanism when the collision start

Tags: matter.js

```
  Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
    var pairs = event.pairs;
    var objA = pairs[0].bodyA;
    var objB = pairs[0].bodyB;
    var objALabel = pairs[0].bodyA.label;
    var objBLabel = pairs[0].bodyB.label;
    //if --- circle 0
    if (objALabel === 'Circle0' && objBLabel === 'Player') {
      Matter.Body.setVelocity(entities.Circle0.body, {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      });
      Matter.Body.setPosition(entities.Circle0.body, {
        x: randomBetween(25, Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH - 25),
        y: randomBetween(
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 3,
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 8
        ),
      });
    dispatch({type:"updateScore"})
    }
    // if ----- circle 1
    if (
      (objALabel === 'Circle1' && objBLabel === 'Player') ||
      (objALabel === 'Player' && objBLabel === 'Circle1')
    ) {
      Matter.Body.setVelocity(entities.Circle1.body, {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      });

      Matter.Body.setPosition(entities.Circle1.body, {
        x: randomBetween(25, Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH - 25),
        y: randomBetween(
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 3,
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 8
        ),
      });
    }
    // if --- Bomb
    if (
      (objALabel === 'Bomb' && objBLabel === 'Player') ||
      (objALabel === 'Player' && objBLabel === 'Bomb') ||
      (objALabel === 'Bomb' && objBLabel === 'Boundary')
    ) {
      Matter.Body.setVelocity(entities.Square.body, {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      });
      Matter.Body.setPosition(entities.Square.body, {
        x: randomBetween(25, Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH - 25),
        y: randomBetween(
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 3,
          Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT / 8
        ),
      });
    }
  });
  Matter.Engine.update(engine, time.delta);

  return entities;
};

export default Physics;
```

this is my physics.js file

I am trying to dispatch score when the collision happened but whenver i try to do it, the score increase infinitely.
is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. Instead of repeating the same paragraph twice (I assume to bypass the post filter), please add details. Thanks.